# Authorize.net Error: Unable to read response, or response is empty

Tags: authorize.net

I am getting a seemingly sporadic error from Authorize.net calls. This is the error that is logged.

```
     [result] => Array
    (
        [response_code] => -1
        [response_reason_code] => 0
        [response_reason_text] => Unable to read response, or response is empty
    )
```

The error started after several months of trouble free operation (~5 orders/day). The customers will get the error and most will just try again. It is usually successful after 2-3 tries. Some customers are successful on their first. This issue has been present for a week now, but it is not consistent. We have had several day long stretches without the error.

I am logging the request and response timestamps and it does not hit the 30 second timeout set in the Magento Authorize.net code. Is there a timeout on the Authorize.net side?

We are on a two server cluster, The error is only happening on one of the servers.

Any clues? I have exhausted my knowledge on this.

Magento Community Edition 1.8.0
Authorize.net (Not Direct Post Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something DNS Lookup was failing. Our server support changed something, I don't know what, but it appears to have fixed it.

This was not a Magento application issue, it was a server issue.

Comment: what host were you with, we're experiencing the same issue on MageMojo

Comment: Can you ask your server support what they fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It also could be curl issue over ssl: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?). In this case restarting apache web server also can be right solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179216/php-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert-path-access-rights

Answer (score 1):

Our issue had to do with the version of `libcurl` (7.19.7) packaged with CentOS 6.6. To be clear, this was just an issue on Authorize.net's sandbox. All of a sudden our test orders to Authorize were failing with the OP's error above.

CURL SSL issues can be fun to debug; to determine the issue, we **temporarily** added the following code to `lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php`

```
public function read()
{
    /** Temporarily Added  to Debug */
    curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
    curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    /** End Temporary Debug $response */

     ...
}
```

Assuming that PHP logging is enabled, this provides verbose information regarding the transaction.  In our case:

```
stderr: "* About to connect() to test.authorize.net port 443 (#0)"
stderr: "*   Trying 184.31.194.197... "
stderr: "* "
stderr: "connected"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "Connected to test.authorize.net (184.31.194.197) port 443 (#0)"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
stderr: "  CApath: none"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "NSS error -5961"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "Closing connection #0"
stderr: "* "
stderr: "SSL connect error"
```

As it turns out, the NSS error lead us to our `libcurl` library which was out of date and was defaulting to TLS Protocol v 1.1; To verify, I temporarily added `curl_setopt($this->_getResource(), CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` to the `read` method above.  Indeed, this allowed the transaction to proceed.

#### Solution

I updated `libcurl` to the current version to utilize TLS 1.2 by default. This will definitely vary by Linux flavor so please do not take verbatim but as an example.

For example:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.42.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf curl-7.42.1.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.42.1
./configure --prefix=/usr
make; make install
ldconfig -v
```

`curl --version` to verify that libcurl was updated.